# Python: multiple client threaded chat server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am trying to build a chat server that handles multiple clients. I am trying to handle each connected client on a new thread. The problem is that I am really confused on how to forward the message received from a client to the intended receiver. I mean client-1 to client-5. I am very new to socket programming. So any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Start here: http://twistedmatrix.com

Comment: can't it be done without twisted? I really wanted to learn the idea behind implementing it.

Comment: Read beej's guide to network programming. It's in C but python just wraps this same API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pseudo-design for your server.  I'll speak in programming language agnostic terms.

Have a "global hash table" that maps "client id numbers" to the corresponding "socket" (and any other client data).  Any access to this hash table is guarded with a mutex.

Every time you accept a new connection, spin up a thread.  I'm assuming there's something in your chat protocol where a client identifies himself, gets a client id number assigned, and gets added to the session.  The first thing the thread does is adds the socket for this client connection to the hash table.

Whenever a message comes in (e.g. from client 1 to client 5), lookup "client 5" in the hash table to obtain its socket.  Forward the message on this socket.

There's a few race conditions to work out, but that should be a decent enough design.

Of course, if you really want to scale, you wouldn't do the "thread per connection" approach. But if you are limited to about 100 or less clients simultaneously connected, you'll be ok.  After that, you should consider a single-threaded approach using non-blocking i/o.